# Proving the continuity of the function $f(x)=x^\alpha$ through power series

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

The textbook I'm studying on presents the following two theorems:

1. $a^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln{a})^nx^n}{n!}$
2. The function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ converges for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence.

In the exercises, I'm asked to prove that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ is continuous on $[0,\infty[$ if $0\leq\alpha$.

What I did was using the first theorem, but inverting the variable with the constant; that is, I wrote $$f(x)=x^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln{x})^n\alpha^n}{n!}$$ for $x>0$ and $0<\alpha$. 
Since this is also a power series, (1) holds. We just need to calculate $\limsup\frac{\alpha^n}{n!}=\lim \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}=0 $. Therefore, $R=\infty$ and $f$ is continuous for $\ln x<\infty$, that is, for every $x\in]0,\infty[$. It is left to prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$: if $\epsilon>0$, then ,for $\delta=\epsilon^\frac{1}{\alpha}$, $x<\delta$ implies $x^\alpha<\epsilon$, since $f$ is increasing.

Could you help me find out if something's wrong with this proof (also in the writing of it)?